# Confirm device build settings and is there a way to automate the process

Tags: iphone

This is a two parter-

1) I'd like to confirm things to turn on or off prior to loading an app to a device as a 'release' (not for debugging). At some point I read to uncheck LOAD SYMBOLS LAZILY in PREFS > DEBUGGER while debugging code. However, I'd like confirm if that needs to be checked ON again for a release. Second, I have an ARGUMENT set for my project executable as NSZOMBIEENABLED = YES. Do I need to unset that prior to loading to the device?

2) is there a way to add the above items to something like the PROJECT > PROJECT SETTINGS > BUILD area so that, when in Debug these things have the right settings, and when in Release they also have the right settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1- When you start a new project, all the settings mentioned should be as they need to be to run anything.

2- XCode provides you with Debug and Release settings, you can see which one is your active one on the top left corner of the screen at the drop down, so you can set each of the settings diffrently...All you need to do is for release have the correct provisioning profile and for debug to ahve the appropriate provisioning profiles